# Finding maximum disimilar numbers between given range

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

Two numbers (a,b) are said to be similar if a<=10*b and b<=10*a . Now given two range low and high , return a collection containing maximum no of non - similar numbers between given range.

I can only think of Brute force approach. Just Need idea of how to solve this problem with better complexity.

Comment: Can u please correct/reword your post and watch your grammar? It's really hard to get what you mean.

Comment: @marsze problem is clearly stated.. what is not clear to you

Comment: I don't understand this sentence "return a collection containing maximum no of non - similar numbers between given range" Could you elaborate or give examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description I see that two numbers are similar if the bigger one of them is no more than 10 times bigger than small one. So if you want to find maximum set of numbers from range [low...high] so that no two numbers in that set are similar, the solution will be to just start from smallest number in the range, i.e. from "low", and every time take next smallest number which is not similar to any number in the set (or its same if you just check if it is not similar to max element in the set).

algorithm:

take **low**, then **10 * low + 1**, **10 * (10 * low + 1) + 1**, etc... until it exceeds **high** limit.

Comment: can u explain the logic behind this answer. why it will always start from low.

Comment: It doesn't have to start from low, but that is easier to understand for people/more natural to count UP. You could also solve this by:

Take *high*, then *high / 10 - 1*, *ans / 10 - 1*, etc. until the next calculate answer is below the *low* limit.

Comment: Now of course, the interesting bit is to prove/disprove that you get the same number of elements whether you start from the lower or the upper end ;)

Comment: what is the complexity of above approach... remember i need to find a set with maximum no of non dismilar elements.. so i need to run above algo for all numbers from low to high..right?

Comment: This approach's complexity is O(log10(high - low)), so its pretty fast. Regarding proof, if we start from **high** and go backward, we do same operation(division by 10 and increment by 1) in reverse order, and we will end up in some position equal or close to **low**, which means we could just start from that position and go forward to high by getting same numbers. So going backward or forward doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, this should work:

```
// start with smallest number:

var numbers = [];
var number = range.lowest;
// while not reached end of range
while (number <= range.highest) {
    // add this number;
    numbers.push(number);
    // find next not similar number
    number = numbers * 10 + 1;
}

// start with highest number:

var numbers = [];
var number = range.highest;
// while not reached end of range
while (number >= range.lowest) {
    numbers.push(number);
    // find next non-similar number
    var newNumber = Math.floor(number / 10.0);
    if (numNumber == number / 10.0);
        newNumber--;
    number = newNumber;
}
```

The latter approach could maybe find more numbers, than the first one, try it. However, there will probably always be different sets of non-similar number with equal size possible.